# Django REST API - Is it possible to create one routers.py per app?

Tags: python, django, python-3.x, django-rest-framework

Hello I've setup a Django project that includes a REST api, so far this is the project structure:

```
django
│
├───apps
│   ├───store
│   |       admin.py
│   |       apps.py
│   |       models.py
│   |       serializers.py
│   |       tests.py
│   |       urls.py
│   |       views.py
│   |       viewsets.py
│   |       __init__.py
│   ├───accounts 
│           admin.py
│           apps.py
│           models.py
│           serializers.py
│           tests.py
│           urls.py
│           views.py
│           viewsets.py
│           __init__.py
├───main
        asgi.py
        router.py
        settings.py
        urls.py
        wsgi.py
        __init__.py
```

Inside main/urls.py I have something like this (which is setting up the API url endpoint by including the routers.py):

```
from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import path, include
from .router import router

urlpatterns = [
    # Default urls
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    path('api/', include(router.urls)),
    path('', include('apps.store.urls')),
]
```

Inside the main/routers.py I am registering all my viewsets for all the project:

```
from rest_framework.routers import DefaultRouter
from apps.store.viewsets import ItemViewSet, PurchaseViewSet, ReceiptViewSet
from apps.accounts.viewsets import ProfileViewSet, TransactionViewSet

router = DefaultRouter()
router.register('items', ItemViewSet)
router.register('purchases', PurchaseViewSet)
router.register('receipts', ReceiptViewSet)
router.register('profiles', ProfileViewSet)
router.register('transactions', TransactionViewSet)
```

Everything works well but my issue is that in this routers.py I will have to register all the ViewSets for the whole project, I'm guessing this doesn't help with modularity and can make this file big and confusing.

**QUESTION:** 
Is it possible to create one routers.py per app, and then somehow import and merge them in the main/routers.py or is there any other way of registering the viewsets for each app inside each respective app? Or is there some other recommended method?

I hope the question is clear, many thanks!

Comment: Just import `router` from where you defined it and run `router.register()` whereever you like. Make sure not to have circular imports!

Comment: Thanks for your feedback but it seems I needed router.registry.extend()

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just found out that the best way is to import the router from the app and use the router.registry.extend method.

First in the routers.py I will name the router something unique to avoid name collisions when merging them

```
router_store = DefaultRouter()
router_store.register('items', ItemViewSet)
router_store.register('purchases', PurchaseViewSet)
router_store.register('receipts', ReceiptViewSet)
```

Then the main routers.py, I will import all my routers, then create a new router and extend it using them routers.py:

```
from store.routers import router_store
from accounts.routers import router_accounts

router = DefaultRouter()
router.registry.extend(router_store.registry)
router.registry.extend(router_accounts.registry)
```

Answer (score 0):

My solution might be complicated, and I haven't worked with Django, nor REST api before. However, I was thinking along the lines of using Pathlib, and it loops through all of the apps, finding the location of the ViewSet. Then, using regex, finds the names of the ViewSets and writes them to a file with a list of all the things. Then, the routers.py reads the file, and loops through each ViewSet in the file.